# VBA listbox issue

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I've got an issue with my listbox.  In the user form initialize event I'm using the following code to populate it:

```
RecordSelectionBox.List = WorkingCopy.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:P20").Value
```

Which works out fine.  I have column width adjustments which also work out fine.  Once the user has selected a record, a line from the listbox I'm setting the captions of a bunch of labels to the value of the listbox columns.  It fills out label captions 1 to 15 just fine.  When it hits 16 I get an error  "Could Not Get the Column Property.  Invalid Argument"  "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'"

Here is the code:

```
Explanation.Caption = RecordSelectionBox.Column(16)
```

a debug.print of RecordSelectionBox.ColumnCount shows that I indeed have 16 columns.  The explanation field is the longest of the fields I'm using, but I'm not sure that I see how that would become an issue.  If anyone has an idea, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the First Column of the listbox starts with `0`

Your first Label should be

```
Label1.Caption = RecordSelectionBox.Column(0)
```

and the 16th should be

```
Explanation.Caption = RecordSelectionBox.Column(15)
```

Comment: Yeah, I looked at my output as soon as I noticed it was off I picked that up.  I was most definitely being a dope.  Thanks for the info.